# Iterate array with specific column from database

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, pdfmake

I would like to iterate the array body table after the array header table of PDFMake using Node.js where I get the data from an SQLite database:

```js
function setListOrder() {
   const list = []

   var row = JSON.stringify(result2);
   var rows = JSON.parse(row);

   for (let orders of [row]) {
      list.push([
         {
            text: `${orders.nama_prd}`,
            aligment: 'left',
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 6
         },
         {
             text: `${orders.stok}`,
             aligment: 'right',
             bold: true,
             fontSize: 6
         },
         {
             text: `${orders.harga}`,
             aligment: 'right',
             bold: true,
             fontSize: 6
         }
      ])
   }
}
```

PDFMake table (I only iterate the body table not the header table):

```
{
   table: {
      headerRows: 1,
      widths: [60, 10, 34],

      body: [
         [
            {
               text:'Menu',
               alignment:'left',
               bold:true,
               fontSize:6
            },
            {
               text:'Qty',
               alignment:'right',
               bold:true,
               fontSize:6
            },
            {
               text:'Hrg',
               alignment:'right',
               bold:true,
               fontSize:6
            }
         ],

         setListOrder()

      ]
   },
   layout:'headerLineOnly',
   margin:[-40,0,-40,0] //[kiri, atas, kanan, bawah]
}
```

Error:

[image]